# identifier "ostream" is undefined error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators, ostream

i need to implement a number class that support operator << for output.
i have an error: "identifier "ostream" is undefined" from some reason eventhough i included  and try also

here the header file:

Number.h

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H
#include <iostream>
class Number{
public:
//an output method (for all type inheritance from number):
virtual void show()=0;

//an output operator:
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Number &f);


};

#endif
```

why the compiler isnt recognize ostream in the friend function?

Comment: Because as with all standard library types and functions, there just *is no* `ostream`. There's only `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the name `ostream` with the name of the namespace that class lives in:

```
    std::ostream
//  ^^^^^
```

So your operator declaration should become:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Number &f);
//     ^^^^^                      ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you could have a `using` declaration before the unqualified name `ostream` appears:

```
using std::ostream;
```

This would allow you to write the `ostream` name without full qualification, as in your current version of the program.

Comment: thanks alot! may using namespace std; will work either?

Comment: Although you shouldn't put `using` in the global namespace in a header, as that might cause name clashes for other users of the header.

Comment: @AviadChmelnik: It will work, but as Mike Seymour points out, it is considered a bad programming practice, because of the high likelihood of introducing name clashes (especially when put in a header at global namespace scope). Rather be selective if you can

Answer (score 0):

Andy Prowl's answer is great but please resist putting "using std::ostream" in a header. If you do this then other compilation units using your header file will also have this namespace 'used' by default and you can get nasty compilation errors with namespace clashes.

Comment: `using std::ostream` puts one name into the namespace where it's used: `ostream`. That's nowhere near as big a problem as `using namespace std;`, which puts **every** name from `std` into that namespace.

Comment: Other compilation units will only get the `ostream` name, not the namespace. Still, I agree that it is  a bad idea.